# Scheduling a Task in command prompt

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am trying to set a ftp upload to be scheduled whether or not the user is logged into their account.  What i have so far is:

```
schtasks /create /sc once /tn "name" /tr "o:\upload.cmd" /st 15:15
```

I am running this at a elevated command prompt but it will only run when i am logged on.  I have tried specifying `/RU` system, but this results in the command not being executed.  Here is the code for that as well:

```
schtasks /create /sc once /tn "name" /tr "o:\upload.cmd" /ru system /st 15:15
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your o:\ drive is an mapped drive try to set full path to the file like this :

```
"\\servername\myfoldername\upload.cmd"
```

If the issue persist, config in Action panel like this:

**Program:** `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`

**Add argumetns** (optional) : `"/C schtasks /create /sc once /tn "name" /tr "o:\upload.cmd" /st 15:15"`

Comment: Did not use exactly what you had there but i've got it working correctly now thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It could be a limitation of the SYSTEM account. We have that issue with a service we provide, it can't access network paths.

Try `/RU "Network Service"` - whether this works however will be dependant on the contents of the file you're running and what it's trying to connect to.

EDIT: OHWAIT I assume the o: drive is a mapped network drive? If this is the case you will only be able to access the path of that script as the user while they are logged in. Otherwise you'll want to use Network Service as above (assuming it has access to the drive, else a domain account) and access the share directly, ie with `\\server\share\script.cmd`

Comment: unfortunatly that did not work, the contents of the file that i am running is: `open hostname
username
password
cd styles
put o:\Test.txt
quit`

Comment: So would i want to put `\\server\share\script.cmd` in place of `/tr "o:\upload.cmd`, and yes o is a mapped network drive

Comment: `/tr \\server\share\upload.cmd` yeah. If you go into Computer you can get these details, it will say something like "Share (\\server) (O:)"

Comment: see http://i.snag.gy/LQL1X.jpg for example, for this I drive the path would be \\nas2\Images

Comment: Both `SYSTEM` and `NETWORK SERVICE` authenticate on the network as the computer account (`COMPUTERNAME$`) when on a domain, so it can work as long as the computer account has access to the share (even implicitly, like through `Authenticated Users`).

Comment: Thanks for that, it is helping i can see now that it is trying to run the problem that i am running into now is correctly putting the file path into the file that executes the code i listed in my comment `open hostname...` i have edited it to this `ftp -s:\\DBSERVER\NAME\script\ftp_script.bat` it flashs on the screen for a second but does nothing thank you for your help

Comment: I think Kekimian is onto the answer to that, set the program to `cmd` and the arguments to `/c \\server\share\upload.cmd`, might do the trick.